# Is there any way to use purgecss on php files?

Tags: php, uncss, css-purge

I have a project where I'm not using any framework or template engine, just plain php. I came across this PurgeCSS plugin that I would like to try as all the pages in the project follow a very similar theme and I think are not using much css rules from the Bootstrap CSS that I have included.

Comment: I don't think it is really meant to run "hot" but instead run every once in a while, like on a build, so you'd probably be looking at the CLI: https://purgecss.com/CLI.html#usage

Answer (score 3):

My bad, I didn't try it before posting this question.
On their website it says it can work with blade files but I realized
blade files are written in PHP after all and I tried purgecss CLI on my project,
It worked and my bootstrap.min.css is now 40KB which was 153KB before.